# Using Model Factory getting [BadMethodCallException] Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::fishes()

Tags: php, laravel, seed

I am trying to SEED my DB using MODEL FACTORY. I have written the following code. But when i run **php artisan db:seed** , it Shows :

```
[BadMethodCallException]                                              
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::fishes()
```

My Code :

```
factory(App\Bear::class, 10)->create()->each(function($u) {
            $u->fishes()->save(factory(App\Fish::class)->make());
        });
```

Any help will be appreciated. TIA ..

Comment: Do you have a fishes() method on your Bear class ?

Comment: Btw having such thing as *fishes* will make working with Laravel one idea harder. *Fish* is uncountable, if you wanna know how Laravel pluralize models, look at `Illuminate\Support\Pluralizer`. Also take a look at the property `$uncountable`.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Yes I had fish() method , now renamed it fishes() . But now it shows "Class Fish Not Found"

Comment: @NehalHasnayeen Bro just have u got me ??

Comment: in which file & line no does that error occurred?

Comment: it shows when i run php artisan db:seed , i mean in my console the error shows

Comment: run [ php artisan db:seed -vvv ] command, it'll show you the file & line no

Comment: PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Fish' not found in /opt/lampp/htdocs/blog/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php on line 733

Comment: give full error stack trace

Answer (score 0):

Out of curiosity: are your model's functions public or protected?

Make sure they are public, like:

```
public function historico()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Historico', 'participante_id');
}
```

It works fine for me.